# Failed to initialize to firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, dialogflow-es

Doing a basic inquiry chatbot app on dialogflow using firebase as our database and for some reason, the code works like when it wants to.

Majority of the time, it doesn't work, it keeps providing this error "*Not available*"

But it actually did work twice with no changes to the code, which leads me to think that it is a database issue, if so, is there any way to solve it?

The code and the database will be below.

The code is currently being hard coded into "Animation" but it still does not work.

```
function getCourseMotto(agent){

    if (action === 'CD_CMotto') { 
    var FullTimecourse = agent.parameters.Course;
    //For course
    //const product = request.body.queryResult.parameters.motto.trim();
    const ref = db.ref(`CourseCategory/Full-Time/Animation/CourseMotto`);

    //const ref = db.ref('Course Category/Full-Time/Animation');
    return 
    ref.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        const product = snapshot.val();
        if (product === null) {
            response.json({
                fulfillmentText: `No data found.`
            });
            return ;
        }

        else{
        response.json({
            fulfillmentText: `The course motto ${FullTimecourse} is ${product}`,
            source: action

        });
            return ;
        }

    }).catch((err) => {
        response.json({
            fulfillmentText: `I don't know what is it error`
        });
        return;
    });
```

[image]

we have also noticed that when the app connects to the database within 11ms, it works, but it usually takes much longer than that, which is probably the reason why it does not.

Comment: Where did you initialize the action variable?